# Real time database REST API Constraint index field must be a JSON primitive

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to make a query to the Real-time database from google using their rest API.
this is how the data of "waiters" path looks like :

```
{
     "-Kb2dYPV0yUXpD_1moc9": {
     "id": "Ky7gTz0BFyRudih0DhSAe3lwci13",
     "role": "normal"  
     },  

     "-Kb2etFm1xHd8sSsESeK": {
     "id": "VRBNr5OnMQaDoLpkKppapyDW8JZ2",
     "role": "admin"
     },
 }
```

On the client-side, I know the id and what I would like to get is the role (i.e "admin" or whatever it is) but I don't know the autogenerated location-id ("-Kb2etFm1xHd8sSsESeK").
Does someone know how to proceed?

I tried :

```
static Future<RoleType> fetchRole(String userId, String token) async {
try {
  var url =
      "https://xxx.firebaseio.com/waiters.json?orderBy=\"id\"&equalTo=\"" +
          "$userId\"" +
          "?auth=" +
          token;
  final response = await http.get(url);
  final extractedData = json.decode(response.body);
  
  if (extractedData == null) return null;
  return RoleType(extractedData['role']);
} catch (error) {
  print("[fetchRole]:: " + error.toString());
  throw error;
}
```

}

the URL without the token gives :

```
https://xxx.firebaseio.com/waiters.json? 
orderBy="id"&equalTo="VRBNr5OnMQaDoLpkKppapyDW8JZ2"?auth=token
```

But I get this error :
{error: Constraint index field must be a JSON primitive}

I still get this error when I update the rules as follow:

```
{
"rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",  // 2020-11-9
    ".write": "auth != null",  // 2020-11-9
    "waiters": {
          ".indexOn": ["id"]
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it works now. I don't know why... Mysteries of CS.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just got the same error when i was playing with ionic with angular.

It turn out one of my character is not an English character, i typed “” instead of "" in Chinese character.

Hope this help if anyone passing by ;)

Comment: Interesting, usually “” is a common MS Word formatting of "", possibly it can also happen through copy-pasting from Word.